# if i use highly nested data in firebase but acess them directly by their key value , will it affect performace?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I dont have to write data at all .
I know other disadvantages of nested data in Firebase.
Just wants to know, will it affect my performance even if I access data directly by their key values, if yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depth is not a factor that affects speed on a technical level. Firebase can as quickly look up a node at level 30 as it can at level 1. The by fast major contributing factors to performance are the size of the data your app reads/writes and the available bandwidth.

But years of experience with Firebase has shown that deeply nested data often goes hand in hand with performance problems. It's not a causal relation, but often developers pick nested structures that are simply the wrong data structure for their apps use-cases.

This really depends on the data structure and the way you access it. Which makes this question way too broad in it's current form. For good introductions to the topic, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I just ran across this and I'm not familiar with Firebase. But I work with Relational DB's (and making them more nosql like as well). If you access data by a key value pair. Retrieving the VALUE by the key will always be really quick. But then you might still need to perform subqueries, or look in your nested object. This will certainly take more processing time. Without much  more detail I don't think anyone can give you a solid answer.

But the short answer is: If you want all data fast and you can get it by a key directly, it will be extremely fast.

But if you want to do more joins and processing on the returned data, it's probably better to normalize out or even denormalize and store that data.